# X86_64 call convention issue

Tags: calling-convention

As we know, X86_64 use register rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8, r9 to store normal function's arguments, and use stack memory to store large argument, and use xmm to store float and double argument. But in my code, the function 'myuprobe_sum_dww_ptr' is wired. It doesn't use rdi to store the first argument but to store a local variable. Please see the code below, and I have commented the register usage information in the code. Could anyone help to explain?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
struct double_wraper
{
    double data;
};
struct double_wraper_wraper
{
    double_wraper_wraper()
    {
        dp = new double_wraper();
    }
    ~double_wraper_wraper()
    {
        delete dp;
    }
    uint32_t a;
    struct double_wraper d;
    struct double_wraper* dp;
};

// a -> rdi, b -> rsi
uint32_t myuprobe_sum_int(uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
    //printf("%u + %u = %u, addr = %p\n", a, b, &a);
    return a + b;
}

// d1 -> rsi, d2 -> rdx, v -> rcx
double_wraper_wraper myuprobe_sum_dww_ptr(const double_wraper_wraper* d1, const double_wraper_wraper* d2, uint32_t v)
{
    double_wraper_wraper d3; // d3 -> rdi, why??????????????
    d3.a = d1->a + d2->a + v;
    d3.d.data = d1->d.data + d2->d.data;
    d3.dp->data = d1->dp->data + d2->dp->data;
    //printf("%u + %u = %u, addr = %p\n", d1->a, d2->a, d3.a, d1);
    //printf("%lf + %lf = %lf, addr = %p\n", d1->d.data, d2->d.data, d3.d.data, d1);
    printf("%lf + %lf = %lf, addr = %p\n", d1->dp->data, d2->dp->data, d3.dp->data, d1);
    return d3;
}

// d1 -> rdi, d2 -> rsi, d3 -> rdx, v -> rcx
double_wraper myuprobe_sum_dw_ptr(const double_wraper* d1, const double_wraper* d2, const double_wraper_wraper* d3, uint32_t v)
{
    double_wraper d4;
    d4.data = d1->data + d2->data + d3->d.data;
    //printf("%lf + %lf + %lf = %lf, addr = %p\n", d1->data, d2->data, d3->d.data, d4.data, d1);
    return d4;
}

int main()
{
    while(1) {
        double_wraper_wraper d4, d5;
        d4.a = rand();
        d4.d.data = rand() + (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
        d4.dp->data = rand() + (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
        d5.a = rand();
        d5.d.data = rand() + (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
        d5.dp->data = rand() + (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
        auto d7 = myuprobe_sum_dww_ptr(&d4, &d5, 100);
        uint32_t a,b;
        a = rand();
        b = rand();
        auto c = myuprobe_sum_int(a, b);

        double_wraper d8,d9;
        d8.data = rand() + (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
        d9.data = rand() + (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
        auto d10 = myuprobe_sum_dw_ptr(&d8, &d9, &d4, 100);
        usleep(5000000);
    }
}
```

Compile: g++ test.cpp -o test -g -O0

Comment: The return value is a large structure (`double_wraper_wraper`), so the address of the return value is passed as a [hidden first parameter](https://cs61.seas.harvard.edu/site/2018/Asm2/): "If the return value takes more than eight bytes, then the caller reserves space for the return value, and passes the address of that space as the first argument of the function."

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you very much. I have tested the theory you said. Indeed, if the return value is int32_t, then the first argument become normal which use rdi. And I have checked the X86 ABI doc, and find the description you mentioned: 2. If the type has class MEMORY, then the caller provides space for the return
value and passes the address of this storage in %rdi as if it were the first
argument to the function. In effect, this address becomes a “hidden” first argument. This storage must not overlap any data visible to the callee through
other names than this argument.